# type cast in Case statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
Segment

   1
   2
   3
   4 
  NUll
   5
```

I want to impute 'Other' if the Segment value is null

expected output

```
  Segment

   1
   2
   3
   4 
  Other
   5
```

i have tried

```
 select 
 case when segment is null then 'Other' else segment end as segment 
 from table;
```

It says invalid input syntax for type "numeric":Other

Comment: Is this really needed on the database level? As the answers mention, this requires typecasting so using the data later means it’s in a “wrong” type as a string and not a number. Usually these are done in the presentation layer, but sometimes it is ok to do it in database level.

Answer (score 2):

The `case` expression returns a single type.  The problem is that `segment` is a number, but `'Other'` is a string.  The expression has to make a choice, and it chooses the numeric type (following standard SQL rules).

This is simple to fix.  Just cast `segment`:

```
select (case when segment is null then 'Other' else segment::text end) as segment 
from table;
```

It would be more natural to write this query using `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(segment::text, 'Other') as segment
from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
 case when CAST(segment AS CHAR) IS NULL then 'Other' else CAST(segment AS CHAR)  end as segment 
 from table
```